# How can I transfer Photo projects from one website to another?

Tags: photos, photo-sharing

If I created a photobook in Snapfish, and want to order the same book from Walgreens (for example), I have to download the pictures, reupload, recreate the book, even though both sites use the same software.

Is there any API to transfer pictures, or photo projects (collages, photo books, mugs etc. etc.) between all of the different photo web sites out there?

Answer (score 1):

Tagline of [Pictarine](http://www.pictarine.com/) is *"All your photos in one place"* ... but in fact, it integrates only Facebook, Flickr and Picasa photo services.
See the [features](http://www.pictarine.com/#/features) page for more infos.